Create CSV file with PHP using a WHILE statement with a twist
Data from the table
123 CA
456 FL
33  CA
This works:
$file_name = "table.csv";
$sql="SELECT filename,state FROM table1"; 
$result=mysqli_query ($dbc,$sql);
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'a');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        
        fputcsv($fp, $row);

    }

fclose($fp);
$str=file_get_contents($file_name);
file_put_contents($file_name, $str);

Output:
123 CA
456 FL
33  CA
But if I want to parse the data and revise/insert variables as needed. I am not sure how to pass the data, line by line, to the csv file
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
     $filename1 = $row['filename'];
      if($filename1 > 100){
         $filename = $filename1;
         } else {

         $filename = NULL;
         }

        fputcsv($fp, $filename);

    }

I tried to create an array
$filename = array();
  $filename[] = $row['filename'] . $row['state'];

But the data does not pass correctly (no carriage return) to the csv file
The desired output:
123 CA
456 FL
EDIT:
I updated the code as such:
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {


$filename[] = ['filename' => $row['filename'], 'state' => $row['state']];


fputcsv($fp, $filename);
       
    
 }

But I end up with this result:


try this structure
$filename[] = ['filename' => $row['filename'], 'state' => $row['state']];

This is a typo question. If you change $filename[] to $filename, your code will work.  You could certainly avoid the PHP condition by writing it in the SQL. Stack Overflow already has countless pages dedicated to exporting mysql results to a csv file.

To modify the data before you write it to a CSV file, you can create a new Array within the While Loop and pass it to fputcsv. Based on your requirement here is my code:
$file_name = "table.csv";
$sql = "SELECT filename, state FROM table1"; 
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

if ($result) {
    $fp = fopen($file_name, 'a');
    if ($fp) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $filename = ($row['filename'] > 100) ? $row['filename'] : NULL;
            $data = [$filename, $row['state']];
            fputcsv($fp, $data);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        echo "Error opening the file.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error executing the query.";
}



This resolved the issue on my end. The key takeaway for me, a simple syntax issue the expert takes for granted, but an array is created by merely encasing the elements in brackets - [ ]. That means I can do all the data manipulation I need to grab whatever variable I want, name the variable, then pack it inside of the bracketed array. A major revelation for me!

@cdr1 I'm glad the solution worked for you! Indeed, creating arrays in PHP with [] is quite straightforward and powerful. It allows for easy data manipulation and variable inclusion. Keep experimenting with this approach, and you'll find it very handy for various tasks
